# Load a div into a webview on Android

Tags: android, webview

I have an Android app, which contains a WebView, and I would like to display in it not a webpage, but only a div from that webpage. I should mention that I do not have access to that page.

Comment: Are there any answers that don't include, "use this library"?  It seems such overkill to import an entire library to do one little bit of trimming.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would recommend [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). It's larger than tagsoup but provides inbuilt functionality to pull the HTML from the URL and is super easy to use. For example if you want to pull a `div` with id `example` you would do the following:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements ele = doc.select("div#example");
```

Then to load the HTML you've extracted into your web view you would do:

```
String html = ele.toString();
String mime = "text/html";
String encoding = "utf-8";
webView.loadData(html, mime, encoding);
```

Comment: this works, i get the html, but i get webpage not available in the webview

Comment: I can't really give you much without more info. If you're getting the HTML then it's probably a valid URL. Are you sure you're doing `loadData()` and not `loadUrl()`, and have you tried outputting the HTML to see what it is?

Comment: I managed to get it working after using loadDataWithBaseURL. Thanks!

Comment: How you can preserve style ?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to load the HTML of the page yourself, extract the div contents and pass it to the WebView as a string.  You may find an HTML parser library (e.g. [tagsoup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/)) useful for this.

Comment: Thank you! could you give some example on this approach?