# Fit HTML <div> to screen in webview - Android

Tags: android, html, webview

I got page looks like this

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class='canvas'>
 Some content here, table other divs and others
</div>
</html>

div.canvas {
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 0px;
width: 600px;
}
```

I need to fit "canvas" div to screen in android webView. Unfortunately I can't edit page on server.

Is there any other option instead of download html string, them edit it local and display it in webView ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325404/load-a-div-into-a-webview-on-android

Comment: If you can edit the HTML, you can insert a viewport meta element in the head. But you are asking how to do it without changing the sources? Well, there's always the pinch zoom...

Answer (score 0):

With css you can set the height to 100%, the issues is making sure your WebView is set to fill_parent as well, it won't work with a wrap_content setting

Comment: ye i set webView as match_parent, i will edit css if theres no other option to do it

Comment: It does seem that will be the only way. You can parse it with a regular expression or JSoup