# Android Load Apart of url to webview

Tags: android, url, webview

I want to load a part of Website to Webview. Not completed Website.
How can I do it?
It is similar this question.
[Load a div into a webview on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325404/load-a-div-into-a-webview-on-android)
But the answer only load text. not have Image.
Any one there?

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a HTML file with a frame (or iframe) in it and save it in your assets folder.
2.Load your file in webview from assets .

Comment: It is not hat i mean. I want to load data from other website.

Comment: Yes I know. You must create a HTML with a frame in local but link it to your website. 
You can have a local HTML with a online frame in it. :)
Frame is look like a window and you can show a part of a site in it.

Comment: I have a html page like that:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="iframe" src="http://www.w3schools.com" style="width:100%; height:1000px"></iframe>
</body>
</html>

And I load to webview
  WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
  view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/TestPage.html");

The problem is webview load whole webpage. while I only want load one div such as 
<div id="maincol">

Comment: You must limit your iframe with css to show only a part (for example a div) of a website.
And if you wanna ask me how I can limit it, I will tell you that it's another question. :)